# Is it possible to do MVC model binding outside of ASP.NET core... but in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin.forms, asp.net-core-mvc, prism, model-binding, prism-6

I am using Xamarin Prism, which allows for URL-style parameters to be used for navigation.

Rather than parsing the string and manually updating my models, I'd like to reuse (anything) that might already exist.

Is it possible to do MVC style model binding for a HTTP GET but for an arbitrary url string?